# Connect certain cells in a table across rows and columns

Tags: html, cell

How can I do this, and is it possible?

Please try a bit of noobish idiocy, I can't describe it better

```
| Monday  | Tuesday       | Wednesday |
+---------+---------------+-----------+
| School  | Art           | Verb      |
| Lunch   | The 3 Rows    |           |
| Roses   | are           |           |
| Useless | 1 cell        |           |
| Dump    | Number        | Things    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about the `colspan` and `rowspan` to understand how to do this yourself, it's very simpl once you know how:

- https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/